Creating reusable components in android studio
I'm creating an app where the user can add services that will be run periodically. I want all the added services to appear in a scrollable layout with tabs that display their name, a run button and a delete (not added yet) button.
My current approach (which is the way I would go about it in react) has been to define some xml that looks like this and dynamically add n number of these tabs as needed passing in the values that it might need (i.e. the record associated with this particular tab):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtServiceName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Run" />

</LinearLayout>

I was hoping to have a Java class that is somehow associated with this tab and to then dynamically spawn as many as I need from the relevant fragment. Is this possible or am I thinking about this all wrong?
I've tried creating my ServiceTab class as a child of the View class and the ViewGroup class but I can't get either to work. Are either of these right or is there another class I need to use for this? Also, please let me know if this is not a very Android way of building the ui, most of my UI experience comes from React so I am used to just creating components whenever I might need to dynamically spawn something

Not sure if this is the recommended way to go about it but I did it with this as the xml for the ServiceTab:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.ServiceTab">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtServiceName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Run" />

</LinearLayout>

And making it a fragment like this:
public class ServiceTab extends Fragment {

    ServiceTabBinding binding;

    public ServiceTab()
    {}

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = ServiceTabBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();


        MainActivity act = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        return root;
    }
}

`
And I can now generate as many of these as I need like this:
    private void createServiceTabs()
{
    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();

    for(Service s : relatedServices)
    {
        // add service tab
        fragTransaction.add(binding.serviceTabsLayout.getId(), (Fragment) new ServiceTab(), "frag"+s.name.toString());

    }
    fragTransaction.commit();
}

